# How to remove permanent/pre-installed Chromium extensions in Linux?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, chromium

I am using Chromium (not Chrome) under Debian 9. How can I remove this extension:

[image]

[image]

Obviously, it cannot be removed by clicking "remove" and it cannot be found under its ID in

```
/home/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/
```

Is is stored elsewhere or maybe even 'hardcoded' into the Chromium source code?

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q seems  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: I would suggest to try https://unix.stackexchange.com or https://askubuntu.com .

Comment: Don't know about linux but maybe some insight here>>>>https://www.chromium.org/administrators

Comment: Thank you, I have reposted the question on the other boards.

Comment: This extension is a core part of the browser, see https://crbug.com/768486. It's externally connectable to allow any 3rd party site to use U2F tokens. This capability is currently being used by Facebook, GitHub, and others. There are two methods to remove it: 1) find and use a special utility to reassemble `resources.pak` and delete this extension, 2) disable it in the source code of chromium and build your own chromium binary.

Comment: That's component extension. Component extensions are baked into the browser during development process and can't be removed from the browser.